# how to testfor a player that selected an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How to use the scoreboard command to testfor for a player that selected a snowball, namely "Blast" in Minecraft 1.9?

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectedItem` compound holds a copy of the player's currently-held item (minus the `Slot` tag). All item data that is not the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, or `Slot`, must be placed within a single `tag` compound.

```
/scoreboard players set @a OBJ 0
/scoreboard players set @a OBJ 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:snowball",tag:{display:{Name:"Blast"}}}}

/say Players holding the item: @a[score_OBJ_min=1]
```

---

As of 1.9 you will want to use "tags" instead of scores when labeling the player, which is more efficient and does not require an objective:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=holding] remove holding
/scoreboard players tag @a add holding {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:snowball",tag:{display:{Name:"Blast"}}}}

/say Players holding the item: @a[tag=holding]
```